# Documenting attributes of abstract base classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abc

I have an abstract base class, and every descendant is expected to have certain attributes (of type str, int, etc), hence it makes sense to document those attributes in the base class. What is the recommended format for documenting these attributes in Python 3.6+?

Comment: Perhaps looking at the [abc module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/abc.html) might give you some ideas.

Comment: [Type hints](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The best source might be PEP 257, specifically the guidance on subclassing.

From [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

> The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the public methods and instance variables. If the class is intended to be subclassed, and has an additional interface for subclasses, this interface should be listed separately (in the docstring). The class constructor should be documented in the docstring for its **init** method. Individual methods should be documented by their own docstring.